# facebook-passport with NestJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, nestjs, passport-facebook, passport-facebook-token

I have looked into both `passport-facebook` and `passport-facebook-token` integration with NestJS. The problem is that NestJS abstracts passport implementation with its own utilities such as AuthGuard.

Because of this, `ExpressJS` style implementation that's documented will not work with NestJS. This for instance is not compliant with the `@nestjs/passport` package:

```
var FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token');

passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({facebookId: profile.id}, function (error, user) {
      return done(error, user);
    });
  }
));
```

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@baptiste.arnaud95/how-to-handle-facebook-login-with-nestjs-89c5c30d566c) shows one strategy for implementing `passport-facebook-token` using an unfamiliar interface that isn't compliant with `AuthGuard`.

```
@Injectable()
export class FacebookStrategy {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    use(
      new FacebookTokenStrategy(
        {
          clientID: <YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID>,
          clientSecret: <YOUR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET>,
          fbGraphVersion: 'v3.0',
        },
        async (
          accessToken: string,
          refreshToken: string,
          profile: any,
          done: any,
        ) => {
          const user = await this.userService.findOrCreate(
            profile,
          );
          return done(null, user);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem here is that this seems to be completely unconventional to how NestJS expects you to handle a passport strategy. It is hacked together. It could break in future NestJS updates as well. There's also no exception handling here; I have no way to capture exceptions such as `InternalOAuthError` which gets thrown by `passport-facebook-token` because of the callback nature that's being utilized.

Is there a clean way to implement either one of `passport-facebook` or `passport-facebook-token` so that it'll use `@nestjs/passport`'s `validate()` method? From the documentation: For each strategy, Passport will call the verify function (implemented with the validate() method in @nestjs/passport). There should be a way to pass a `clientId`, `clientSecret` in the constructor and then put the rest of the logic into the `validate()` method.

I would imagine the final result to look something similar to the following (this does not work):

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import FacebookTokenStrategy from "passport-facebook-token";


@Injectable()
export class FacebookStrategy extends PassportStrategy(FacebookTokenStrategy, 'facebook')
{

    constructor()
    {
        super({
            clientID    : 'anid',     // <- Replace this with your client id
            clientSecret: 'secret', // <- Replace this with your client secret
        })
    }


    async validate(request: any, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: Function)
    {
        try
        {
            console.log(`hey we got a profile: `, profile);

            const jwt: string = 'placeholderJWT'
            const user = 
            {
                jwt
            }

            done(null, user);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log(`got an error: `, err)
            done(err, false);
        }
    }

}
```

In my particular case, I am not interested in `callbackURL`. I am just validating an access token that the client has forwarded to the server. I just put the above to be explicit.

Also if you are curious, the code above produces an `InternalOAuthError` but I have no way of capturing the exception in the strategy to see what the real problem is because it isn't implemented correctly. I know that in this particular case the `access_token` I am passing is invalid, if I pass a valid one, the code works. With a proper implementation though I would be able to capture the exception, inspect the error, and be able to bubble up a proper exception to the user, in this case an HTTP 401.

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
```

It seems clear that the exception is being thrown outside of the `validate()` method, and that's why our try/catch block is not capturing the `InternalOAuthError`. Handling this exception is critical for normal user experience and I am not sure what the NestJS way of handling it is in this implementation or how error handling should be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track with the `Strategy` using `extends PassportStrategy()` class setup you have going. In order to catch the error from passport, you can extend the `AuthGuard('facebook')` and add some custom logic to `handleRequest()`. You can [read more about it here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#extending-guards), or take a look at this snippet from the docs:

```js
import {
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    // Add your custom authentication logic here
    // for example, call super.logIn(request) to establish a session.
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }

  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    // You can throw an exception based on either "info" or "err" arguments
    if (err || !user) {
      throw err || new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Yes, this is using JWT instead of Facebook, but the underlying logic and handler are the same so it should still work for you.

Comment: thanks so much Jay, I am not sure how I overlooked this. it is exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you have any idea what type of object `err` is? it seems to be a string which is difficult to parse

Comment: Nope. One of the problems is passport is not a typed package, so who knows what error it is returning.

Comment: This answer also saved me a lot of time.. Maybe they should write it better at the documentation, i also like @randombits was like 'How did i overlook this!'

Comment: How would you propose it written better? [It's already linkable](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#extending-guards), which means it has a header on the page. And every passport strategy is usable with Nest by creating a `Strategy` class and using the built in `AuthGuard()`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used to use the `passport-facebook-token` with older version of nest. To upgrade, the adjustment of the strategy was needed. I am also not interested in the callback url.

This is a working version with `passport-facebook-token` that uses nest conventions and benefits from dependency injection:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'

import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport'
import * as FacebookTokenStrategy from 'passport-facebook-token'

import { UserService } from '../user/user.service'
import { FacebookUser } from './types'

@Injectable()
export class FacebookStrategy extends PassportStrategy(FacebookTokenStrategy, 'facebook-token') {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super({
      clientID: process.env.FB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  }

  async validate(
    accessToken: string,
    refreshToken: string,
    profile: FacebookTokenStrategy.Profile,
    done: (err: any, user: any, info?: any) => void,
  ): Promise<any> {
    const userToInsert: FacebookUser = {
      ...
    }

    try {
      const user = await this.userService.findOrCreateWithFacebook(userToInsert)

      return done(null, user.id) // whatever should get to your controller
    } catch (e) {
      return done('error', null)
    }
  }
}
```

This creates the `facebook-token` that can be used in the controller.